# Setting up multi datacenter Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am working on setting up the Kafka cluster with a multi DC cluster. The intention is to ensure if one DC goes down, both producers and consumers can still able to continue operations without any issues. I came across two options, but not sure what's the difference and how it works.

Option 1: Setting up multiple zookeeper cluster (one cluster per DC)

Setting up multiple zookeepers and each zookeeper will have a set of brokers in a DC. In this scenario will I really get both Active-Active and Disaster Recovery? If 1 DC goes down what will happen to consumers.

Option 2: Setting up Mirror maker with source and target

I understand it's a replication of one cluster to another. But how do I point to both clusters from a consumer or producer perspective? Will it be handled automatically or something I should do it manually?

Any explanation of these options are appreciated.

Comment: 1) Zookeeper will soon be removed from Kafka. 2) You might want to look at https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-cluster-linking-with-confluent-platform/ 3) there's aws blogs about setting up clusters over multiple availability zones, which is basically the same as geographically close datacenters

Comment: Confluent Kafka has a replicator which comes as part of Enterprise edition. If I go with confluent Kafka community edition, will there be any restrictions I need to be worried about? We are not interested in buying an enterprise version.

Comment: There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". There is Confluent Server, or Confluent Platform. You can use MirrorMaker2 in place of replicator, but I was more pointing at the [cluster linking features](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-deployments/cluster-linking/index.html)